# Converter valor para objeto C#

Tags: c#, socket, conversão-de-tipo

Estou fazendo uma integração onde o sistema usa conexão socket, eu envio e recebo mensagens para chegar a um fim, e as mensagens vem nesse formato:

```
aplicacao="Teste"
retorno="1"
sequencial="191"
servico="iniciar"
versao="1.0.0"
```

Minha dúvida é, há alguma forma de transformar essas mensagens em objetos?

Edit1:

Método de chamada:

```
private bool transacaoTEF(string formaPagamento, string valor, string parcelas, string tipoTransacao)
    {
        string coleta = string.Empty;
        string resposta = string.Empty;
        int s = TEF.Metodos.Sequencial();
        int sa = 1;
        valor = valor.Replace(",", ".");

        if (!TEF.Metodos.Conectar()) return false;

        Iniciar:

        // INICIAR
        resposta = TEF.Metodos.IniciaTransacao(s.ToString());

        if (resposta.Contains("retorno=\"2\""))
        {
            s += 2;
            goto Iniciar;
        }

        if (resposta.Contains("retorno=\"1\""))
        {
            s += 1;
            resposta = TEF.Metodos.TipoTransacao(valor, s.ToString(), tipoTransacao);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (resposta.Contains("retorno=\"0\""))
            {
                if (resposta.Contains("automacao_coleta_tipo"))
                {
                    using (ColetaTefForm form = new ColetaTefForm(resposta))
                        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            coleta = form.coleta;

                    sa = Convert.ToInt32(TEF.Metodos.RetornaValor(resposta, "automacao_coleta_sequencial"));
                    resposta = TEF.Metodos.AutomacaoColetaInformacao(sa.ToString(), coleta);
                    continue;
                }
                if (resposta.Contains("automacao_coleta_mensagem"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(TEF.Metodos.RetornaValor(resposta, "automacao_coleta_mensagem"));
                    sa = Convert.ToInt32(TEF.Metodos.RetornaValor(resposta, "automacao_coleta_sequencial"));
                    resposta = TEF.Metodos.Processar(sa.ToString());
                    continue;
                }
                if (resposta.Contains("transacao_comprovante"))
                {
                    s = Convert.ToInt32(TEF.Metodos.RetornaValor(resposta, "automacao_coleta_sequencial"));
                    TEF.Metodos.ConfirmarTransacao(s.ToString(), tipoTransacao);
                    TEF.Metodos.Finalizar((s + 1).ToString());
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (resposta.Contains("retorno=\"9\""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(TEF.Metodos.RetornaValor(resposta, "mensagem"));
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Classe "Métodos"

```
public class Metodos
{
    private static TcpClient tcpClient;
    private static NetworkStream networkStream;

    public static bool Conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
            string port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"];
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(host, Convert.ToInt32(port));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MensagemErro(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int Sequencial()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/sequencial.txt"))
                return Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/sequencial.txt"));
            else
            {
                File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/sequencial.txt").Dispose();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MensagemErro(e);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void SalvarSequencial(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/sequencial.txt", s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MensagemErro(e);
        }
    }

    public static string IniciaTransacao(string sequencial)
    {
        return Retorno("aplicacao=\"ProComercio\" " +
                       "versao=\"1.0.0\" " +
                       "retorno=\"1\" " +
                       "sequencial=\"" + sequencial + "\" " +
                       "servico=\"iniciar\"");
    }

    public static string TipoTransacao(string valor, string sequencial, string tipoTransacao)
    {
        if (valor.Contains(","))
            valor = valor.Replace(",", ".");

        return Retorno("retorno=\"1\" " +
                       "sequencial=\"" + sequencial + "\" " +
                       "servico=\"executar\" " +
                       "transacao=\"" + tipoTransacao + "\" " +
                       "transacao_valor=\"" + valor + "\"");
    }

    public static string AutomacaoColetaInformacao(string sequencial, string informacao)
    {
        return Retorno("automacao_coleta_sequencial =\"" + sequencial + "\" " +
                       "automacao_coleta_retorno=\"0\" " +
                       "automacao_coleta_informacao=\"" + informacao + "\"");
    }

    public static string Processar(string sequencial)
    {
        return Retorno("automacao_coleta_sequencial =\"" + sequencial + "\" " +
                       "automacao_coleta_retorno=\"0\"");
    }

    public static string ConfirmarTransacao(string sequencial, string tipoTransacao)
    {
        return Retorno("sequencial =\"" + sequencial + "\" " +
                       "retorno=\"0\" " +
                       "servico=\"executar\" " +
                       "transacao=\"" + tipoTransacao + "\"");
    }

    public static string Finalizar(string sequencial)
    {
        return Retorno("retorno=\"1\" " +
                       "sequencial =\"" + sequencial + "\" " +
                       "servico=\"finalizar\"");
    }

    public static string RetornaValor(string resposta, string palavraChave)
    {
        string[] lista = resposta.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string linha = "";
        foreach (string l in lista)
        {
            if (l.Contains(palavraChave + "=\""))
            {
                linha = l;
            }
        }
        return linha.Split(new[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
    }

    public static string ViaEstabelecimento(string nota)
    {
        int inicio = nota.LastIndexOf("transacao_comprovante_1via=\"");
        int final = nota.IndexOf("transacao_comprovante_2via=\"");

        string comprovante = nota.Substring(inicio, final - inicio);
        return comprovante.Split(new[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
    }

    public static string ViaCliente(string nota)
    {
        int inicio = nota.LastIndexOf("transacao_comprovante_2via=\"");
        int final = nota.IndexOf("transacao_data");

        string comprovante = nota.Substring(inicio, final - inicio);
        return comprovante.Split(new[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
    }

    public static string Retorno(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
            {
                networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            }
            byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize));
            string retorno = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            return retorno;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MensagemErro(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void MensagemErro(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro com o V$PagueClient!\n\n" + e, "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Estou usando substring no momento, mas não está preciso, pois algumas respostas vem assim: https://textuploader.com/153ev

Comment: Sim, é possível, apresente o seu código

Comment: Só preciso de um exemplo prático com uma string qualquer, o código é muito extenso para mandar aqui

Comment: Vem sempre no mesmo formato o retorno?

Comment: Sim @GustavoLuciano

Comment: @LeandroAngelo postei o código

Comment: Porque não instancia a classe e passe os atributos ?

Comment: Não entendi bem @JoyPeter, como posso fazer isso? Esses dados que recebo vem como string

Comment: Cria uma classe com os atributos do retorno e depois instancia  passando os valores para respectivo atributo.

Comment: Nessa parte que estou tendo dificuldades @JoyPeter, como consigo fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro cria a classe com as propriedade do retorno

```
public class PropriedaRetorno
{
    public string Aplicacao { get; set; }
    public string Retorno { get; set; }
    public string Sequencial { get; set; }
    public string Servico { get; set; }
    public string Versao { get; set; }
}`
```

Aqui fazemos a conversão, recebe um parâmetro string que é o retorno em string e retorna o objecto. Conforme a estrutura da string que apresentaste essa é lógica é funcional:

```
   public static PropriedaRetorno Convert(string retorno)
    {
        PropriedaRetorno pr = new PropriedaRetorno();
        pr.Aplicacao = GetValeu(retorno, "aplicacao"); 
        pr.Retorno = GetValeu(retorno, "retorno");
        pr.Sequencial = GetValeu(retorno, "sequencial");
        pr.Servico = GetValeu(retorno, "servico");
        pr.Versao = GetValeu(retorno, "versao");
        return pr;
    }
```

A função recebe o retorno e a chave e retorna o valor correspondente a chave.

```
    public string GetValeu(string retorno, string key)
    {
        string valeu = "";
        int i = retorno.LastIndexOf(key + "=\"");
        i += key.Length + 2;
        while (i <= retorno.Length)
        {
            char ch=retorno[i];
            if ( ch== '\"')
                break;
            valeu += ch;
            i++;
        }
        return valeu;
    }
```

Desse modo tu tens maior liberdade, podes adicionar mais atributo na classe e de seguida adicionar também na função Convert o atributo.

ex:  `pr.Sequencial = GetValeu(retorno, "sequencial");`

Comment: Essa forma se aplica a esse tipo de retorno também? https://textuploader.com/153ev

Comment: Não. eu segui apenas o retorno que apresentaste na questão.

Comment: Eu editei um pouco depois de você apresentar a solução, teria uma forma de converter a string desse link?

Comment: Tem. mas eu precisarei saber o começo e o fim do filtro que precisas, e o padrão dessas strings.

Comment: O padrão seria: nome_do_atributo="valor" nome_do_atributo2="valor2"

Comment: Separados um do outro por espaço

Comment: OK, percebi, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Já está editado

Answer (score 2):

Como sua pergunta apesentou um formato de entrada variável fica difícil estipular um formato padronizado de classe para acomodar os seus dados.

O que fiz foi criar um analisador para que aceita uma string qualquer de entrada e devolve um dicionário cujo tanto as chaves e os valores são strings. Esse analisador busca pelo padrão **nome_atributo="valor"** e preenche o dicionário com a chave sendo o **nome_atributo** e valor da chave sendo **"valor"** sem as aspas.

Como recurso de teste eu criei um arquivo chamado `"Entrada.txt"` cujo o conteúdo é o retorno que você passou no link https://textuploader.com/153ev.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Analisador
{
   public static Dictionary<string,string> Parse(string entrada)
   {
      //cria o dicionário que será devolvido pela função
      Dictionary<string,string> resultado =new Dictionary<string,string>();

      // Analiza a string de entrada em busca do padrão nome_atributo="valor"
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(entrada, "[^\\s\\\"]+=\\\"[^\\\"]+\\\"");

      //Varre o conjunto de resultados e os armazena no dicionário      
      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
        // separa o atributo de seu valor
        string[] arr = match.Value.Split('='); 

        //Insere a chave sem espaços laterais e o valor sem aspas no dicionário
        resultado.Add(arr[0], arr[1].Replace("\"", ""));
      }

      // retorna o dicionário
      return resultado;
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
      Dictionary<string,string> Valores = Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"Entrada.txt"));      

      foreach(var item in Valores)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
      }
   }
}
```

A partir desse código você pode criar uma classe que atenda suas nescessidades e preencher os campos com os valores do dicionário.

Comment: O [código no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CreativeVengefulQueries) não vou adicionar a resposta pois como é de manuseio publico alguém pode apagar ou modificar. Fica então como comentário. PS: a janela de exibição do Repl.it é meio zoada 'WriteLines' consecutivos não iniciam na primeira coluna.